# Error Editing Google Sheets Swift

Tags: swift, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to edit google sheets from within swift. I used the original Quickstart tutorial by google, but since that is for reading a spreadsheet, I had to slightly edit it for writing to a spreadsheet.

```
//Signing in as normal from the Google Quickstart



//This function is the one I edited, to write to the spreadsheet
func listMajors() {
    output.text = "Getting sheet data..."
    let spreadsheetId = "**********************"
    let range = "Sheet 1!A2"
    let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange.init()
    valueRange.values = [["Hello" as Any]]
    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range: range)
    query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
    service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}
func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket, finishedWithObject result : GTLRSheets_ValueRange, error : NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    print(result)
}
```

It seemed to work fine for the reading spreadsheet, but it is not working for writing to spreadsheet. The app launches, then i get an error alert with this:
[image]

Comment: What scope are you using for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to add solution in objective-C, but i think you will be able to manage conversion

I just have the same problem today.
The solution is simple, when initializing the GIDSignIn

```
// Configure Google Sign-in.
GIDSignIn* signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets, nil];
[signIn signInSilently];
```

Note the scope value. In the quickStart tutorial, kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheetsReadonly is used.

Romain

Comment: forget to add this link : https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing